# Update custom ARAdjust field inside PXLongOperation

Tags: acumatica

Hi I am trying to update a custom field I have on the ARAdjust table.

I am trying to update this from a extended graph inside a PXLongOperation

Here is the code I use to update the field.

```
 Base.SetValueExt(Base.Adjustments.View.Name, adj, "UsrMAFORexETag", rexInvTransID.ToString());
 Base.Actions.PressSave();
```

No errors occur but when I look at the table the field hasnt been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Base.SetValueExt(Base.Adjustments.View.Name, adj, "UsrMAFORexETag", rexInvTransID.ToString());
Base.Adjustments.Update(adj);
Base.Actions.PressSave();
```

Try to update Cache before pressing save. In your example Adjustments cache remains Not modified. That's why nothing happens on pressing save.